# When was the last time that the British Prime Minister and Chancellor of the Exchequer were both former Foreign Secretaries?

Tags: united-kingdom, foreign-policy, prime-minister

Liz Truss and Jeremy Hunt, respectively the British Prime Minister and Chancellor of the Exchequer, are both former Foreign Secretaries.

When was the last time that this was true of the holders of both of those posts?

Answer (score 8):

The last time this was the case was from July 1960 to July 1962, while John Selwyn Brooke Lloyd served as Chancellor during Harold Macmillan’s premiership.

Before his appointment to the role, Lloyd had served as Foreign Secretary since 1955. He had taken over the role from Macmillan himself, who briefly served as Foreign Secretary from April to December of that year.

There was *almost* a brief period during which Boris Johnson (Foreign Secretary, 2016-2018) was Prime Minister, with Philip Hammond (Foreign Secretary, 2014-2016) as Chancellor. However, Hammond resigned as Chancellor about an hour before Johnson took over from Theresa May in July 2019.